# Is there any frameworks to implement throttling mechanism in a microservice?

Tags: rest, microservices, throttling

I develop microservice which communicate within RESTful style.
Is there any ready-to-use frameworks for throttling mechanism implementation?
I use Spring Boot.

Throttling here is a mechanism to reduce frequency of outgoing requests by filtering, for example, duplicate requests.

In my case I think I should use a cache (don't know which one) to filter out duplicate request which was handled already.

And in what period the cache should be cleaned? (daily, hourly, etc)

Please hint me where to dig.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot provides the @Cacheable and similar annotations which indicate that and how a method result should be cached. E.g. @CachePut(value="addresses", condition="#Person.name=='Tom'")
public String getAddress(Person person) {...} will cache the result if the parameter person's name was "Tom". This is an example of how filtering could be implemented.

Since you're using Spring Boot you can pull spring-boot-starter-cache in as a dependency and it will provide you with the annotation and the cache.

It's also possible to define how frequently the cache should be evicted, e.g. with Spring's @Scheduled annotation, the specific frequency being dependent on your use case.

This was just a small insight into the following references:

- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cache-tutorial
- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-evict-cache